# Regex to extract an option from a command line doesn't work as expected

Tags: regex

I'm trying to analyze a command line that may contain a password and as I log the command line I don't want to log the password so I need to replace it with ****.

Here is the command line example :

`myprogram --first-option 10 --update-password mypassword --another-option`

Here is the regex that "should" work (at least for me) but doesn't...

`.*?--update-password\s+(?<pwd>.*?)(\s+--\w+)?.*`

My problem is that the named group "pwd" doesn't match anything because of the `.*?`. But if I try to remove the ***?*** then it matches the whole line, including the next option.

From my understanding the ***?*** should tell the engine that it has to match until it finds something else after, meaning it should match until it finds another option `(\s+--\w+)` or nothing. But it doesn't work that way apparently... I think I've done that many times in the past and it always worked as I wanted. Dunno what I'm missing here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the tool/programming language/code you are using with the regex? Regex pattern only matches strings, replacement is done through the code.

Comment: Why so complicated, why not something simpler like e.g. `--update-password\s+(?<pwd>[^\s]+)`? (Which [seems to work fine](https://regex101.com/r/GpShe5/2))

Comment: How about https://regex101.com/r/OsCF3f/1

Comment: Ok thank you very much for both of your solutions, they work fine. I don't think I can say the question is answered though. I'm really curious why mine is not working. But you're right your approch is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to do the job:

- find: `(^.*?--update-password\s+)\S+(\s+--.*)`
- Replace: `$1*****$2`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/OsCF3f/1)

The reason why your regex doesn't work is because of the optional capture group: `(\s+--\w+)?`